# How do I use aptitude to downgrade/force version of a package?

Tags: aptitude, downgrade

I've decided that I like `aptitude` better than all the alternatives I've tried.  But I can't figure out how to downgrade/force version of a package with it. I have to go back and use `synaptic` for that.

How does one use `aptitude` to downgrade a package?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
sudo aptitude install package-name=package-version
```

For example:

```
$ aptitude versions firefox$

Package firefox:                         
p   45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1             xenial                         500 
i   52.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1     xenial-security,xenial-updates 500
```

Then:

```
sudo aptitude install firefox=45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1
```

And with the GUI:

[image: Downgrade packages with aptitude]