# apt-get install php-soap gives me the wrong version

Tags: apt, php

My version of PHP is 5.6.28-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1

When I do `apt-get install php-soap` I get offered version 7.1 of soap.

When I run `apt-cache madison php-soap` I get this:

```
php-soap | 1:7.1+50+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 | http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
  php-soap |   0.13.0-1 | http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
  php-soap |   0.13.0-1 | http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe Sources
```

... which doesn't look very promising. Why only one version?

I don't understand why I am only offered soap for PHP 7.1, which is a new version. Surely there was a version of soap for the older versions of PHP. Where can I find, and how to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your `apt-cache madison` output, it seems to me that you have access to two different version: `7.1+50+deb.sury.org~trusty+1` and `0.13.0-1`.

If you run:

```
apt-cache policy php-soap
```

I think you should get the `7.1` one as candidate for installation.

If you want to install the older version from official repositories, then run:

```
sudo apt-get install php-soap=0.13.0-1
```

that should do the trick.

Comment: I'm marking this correct - however Ubuntu did not correctly configure the "downgraded" soap version so I'm still struggling with that. I will open a new thread for that.

Comment: @Owen check this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900536/how-do-i-use-aptitude-to-downgrade-force-version-of-a-package/900538#900538) it's may be helpful.

Comment: I followed the instructions on that link - I've opened a new Question - http://askubuntu.com/questions/903554/loading-php-extensions