# downgrade libc6 to 2.23-0ubuntu11.2

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, glibc

I'm running ubuntu16, and last week I installed https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/clang-10_10.0.0-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb.html from ubuntu20 package repository(by simply add ubuntu20 repository to `/etc/apt/sources.list`), and it also installed some new verison libc6/libc6-dev/etc as dependency, causing my environment broken.

Right now I just want to rollback my environment to previous status. Is there any way to reinstall an old version of libc that belongs to ubuntu16?

what I've tried:

```
sudo apt install libc6=2.23-0ubuntu11.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9) but 2.23-0ubuntu11.2 is to be installed
             Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.31-0ubuntu9)
             Depends: libcrypt-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 16, the closest in name is Ubuntu Core 16, however your post uses `apt` commands, yet *yy* releases of Ubuntu are *snap* only. So please be precise with release details, your post is unclear. Please clarify your OS & release details (packages appear to match both 16.04 & 20.04 but not Ubuntu core 16/20; Ubuntu Core 16 will run all *snaps* of Ubuntu Core 20; one beauty of *yy* releases). *Restoring backups will be your easiest solution*

Comment: Assuming 16.04 LTS, esp. desktop. I would suggest you explore your system (`ubuntu-support-status` likely where I'd start) to see how much damage you've done. likely more than shown).  The easiest fix (beyond restoring backups) would be a re-install using existing partitions but avoiding format. It'll cause packages to be noted, system directories wiped, install occurs, then it'll add-back of your additional packages if available in Ubuntu repositories. It's fast & easy, though the wiping system directories does mean more work is required for server setups.

Comment: Try the solution here https://askubuntu.com/q/900536/26246

Comment: 1) "pkgs.org" is not an official Ubuntu repository;  2) Downloading an executing a `.deb` file is a risky way to install software, as you've just discovered; 3) All software in Ubuntu repos can and should be installed with `apt` or your GUI package manager; 4) Official `.deb` files *are* available at https://packages.ubuntu.com (but I would not recommend installing any software this way)