# How to install a specific version of a metapackage and its dependencies?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I'll use the NVIDIA 460 driver as an example.  Here's what happens when I want to try to install version 460.67 instead of 460.80 (which is [buggy](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/nr476z/has_anyone_here_having_issues_with_nvidia_465/), FYI).

```
$ apt-get install -s nvidia-driver-460=460.67-0ubuntu1
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt-get needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-460 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-460 (= 460.67-0ubuntu1) but 460.80-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 is to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-dkms-460 (<= 460.67-1)
                     Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-460 (<= 460.67-1) but 460.80-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 is to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-kernel-source-460 (= 460.67-0ubuntu1) but 460.80-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 is to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-compute-460 (= 460.67-0ubuntu1) but 460.80-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 is to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-extra-460 (= 460.67-0ubuntu1) but 460.80-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 is to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-460 (= 460.67-0ubuntu1) but 460.80-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 is to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-decode-460 (= 460.67-0ubuntu1) but 460.80-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 is to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-encode-460 (= 460.67-0ubuntu1) but 460.80-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 is to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-utils-460 (= 460.67-0ubuntu1) but 460.80-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 is to be installed
                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-460 (= 460.67-0ubuntu1) but 460.80-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 is to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-cfg1-460 (= 460.67-0ubuntu1) but 460.80-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 is to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-ifr1-460 (= 460.67-0ubuntu1) but 460.80-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 is to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-fbc1-460 (= 460.67-0ubuntu1) but 460.80-0ubuntu0.21.04.2 is to be installed
                     Recommends: nvidia-settings but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: nvidia-prime (>= 0.8) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-compute-460:i386 (= 460.67-0ubuntu1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-decode-460:i386 (= 460.67-0ubuntu1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-encode-460:i386 (= 460.67-0ubuntu1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-ifr1-460:i386 (= 460.67-0ubuntu1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-460:i386 (= 460.67-0ubuntu1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-460:i386 (= 460.67-0ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

That's only 1 example I can think of at the moment.

Do I have to list all of the packages I want to install?

Comment: They all exist in the cache.  They're found in "hirsute" repo, not in "hirsute-updates" or "hirsute-security"

Comment: Yami, best is to use `aptitude` or `synaptic` which helps to track automatically top version of each package that fill the requirement. Otherwise, you have to list them one by one with `apt`. Similar to this case: https://askubuntu.com/q/900536/26246

Comment: What is your actual Ubuntu version?

Comment: 21.04.  I also have a system with Neon (based on 20.04) @N0rbert

Comment: Never thought I had a reason to use `aptitude` until you pointed that out.   Thanks! @user.dz

Comment: @YamiYukiSenpai how did it go, were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: I was merely curious about the process in case I ever need to do this.  And I really hate manually listing the package, but at least now I know I can use `aptitude`.  The issue regarding the driver was resolved **for me** (thanks Pop!_OS for not updating the driver XD). @user.dz

Comment: Also, `synaptic` wouldn't have worked in this scenario because the OS wouldn't even boot to login screen.

Comment: @YamiYukiSenpai Nice, Could you make an answer even by coping my comment and add that you chosen a different path.

Answer (score 0):

From @user.dz:

> best is to use `aptitude`. which helps to track automatically top version of each package that fill the requirement. Otherwise, you have to list them one by one with apt. Similar to this case: askubuntu.com/q/900536/26246

In my case, I went with a different route (you can see the link in my post).