# 20.04 (focal) Packages Installed on 22.04 (jammy)

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04

I'm in a bit of a weird spot here. Through upgrading to 22.04 and all the other shenanigans I've gotten up to, I seem to have ended up with packages for 20.04 installed on my 22.04 system. Whenever I try to fix this issue (eg. manually downloading the latest deb and installing it over what I have), it seems as though the whole house of cards comes crashing down, and apt removes everything from the entire desktop environment to libraries and dev headers.

When I run `apt list --installed | grep 20.04`, I get

```
david@david-pc:~$ apt list --installed | grep 20.04

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libcamera0/now 0.r3948.ged591e70-1~ubuntu20.04 amd64 [installed,local]
libfreeaptx0/now 0.1.1.r2.gc176b7d-2~ubuntu20.04 amd64 [installed,local]
libldacbt-abr2/now 2.0.2.3.r4.gaf2dd23-5~ubuntu20.04 amd64 [installed,local]
libldacbt-enc2/now 2.0.2.3.r4.gaf2dd23-5~ubuntu20.04 amd64 [installed,local]
libopenaptx0/now 0.2.0-9~ubuntu20.04 amd64 [installed,local]
libopenfec/now 1.4.2.4-5~ubuntu20.04 amd64 [installed,local]
libpipewire-0.3-0/now 0.3.59.r3.gd22feab-1~ubuntu20.04 amd64 [installed,local]
libpipewire-0.3-modules/now 0.3.59.r3.gd22feab-1~ubuntu20.04 amd64 [installed,local]
libroc/now 0.1.5.r41.gc896873-11~ubuntu20.04 amd64 [installed,local]
libspa-0.2-bluetooth/now 0.3.59.r3.gd22feab-1~ubuntu20.04 amd64 [installed,local]
libspa-0.2-jack/now 0.3.59.r3.gd22feab-1~ubuntu20.04 amd64 [installed,local]
libspa-0.2-modules/now 0.3.59.r3.gd22feab-1~ubuntu20.04 amd64 [installed,local]
libwireplumber-0.4-0/now 0.4.11.r31.g8fa1693-1~ubuntu20.04 amd64 [installed,local]
libyuv0/jammy,now 0.0~git20220104.b91df1a-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
pipewire-alsa/now 0.3.59.r3.gd22feab-1~ubuntu20.04 amd64 [installed,local]
pipewire-audio-client-libraries/now 0.3.59.r3.gd22feab-1~ubuntu20.04 all [installed,local]
pipewire-bin/now 0.3.59.r3.gd22feab-1~ubuntu20.04 amd64 [installed,local]
pipewire-jack/now 0.3.59.r3.gd22feab-1~ubuntu20.04 amd64 [installed,local]
pipewire-locales/now 0.3.59.r3.gd22feab-1~ubuntu20.04 all [installed,local]
pipewire-pulse/now 0.3.59.r3.gd22feab-1~ubuntu20.04 amd64 [installed,local]
pipewire/now 0.3.59.r3.gd22feab-1~ubuntu20.04 amd64 [installed,local]
solaar/now 1.1.5~ubuntu20.04.1 all [installed,local]
wireplumber/now 0.4.11.r31.g8fa1693-1~ubuntu20.04 amd64 [installed,local]
x11proto-core-dev/now 2021.5-3~ubuntu20.04 all [installed,local]
x11proto-dev/now 2021.5-3~ubuntu20.04 all [installed,local]
```

It seems as though most packages there are related to using a pipewire backport PPA (which is now disabled) before I upgraded to 22.04 . Any ideas how to fix this?

EDIT: Thought it may be helpful to include `apt-cache policy` for one of the packages

```
david@david-pc:~/Downloads$ apt-cache policy pipewire
pipewire:
  Installed: 0.3.59.r3.gd22feab-1~ubuntu20.04
  Candidate: 0.3.59.r3.gd22feab-1~ubuntu20.04
  Version table:
 *** 0.3.59.r3.gd22feab-1~ubuntu20.04 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.3.48-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
     0.3.48-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

EDIT:
Fixed most of it, however a few packages remain. Here are the `apt-cache policy` outputs for them

```
david@david-pc:~$ apt-cache policy libopenaptx0
libopenaptx0:
  Installed: 0.2.0-9~ubuntu20.04
  Candidate: 0.2.0-9~ubuntu20.04
  Version table:
 *** 0.2.0-9~ubuntu20.04 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.2.0-6 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
```

```
david@david-pc:~$ apt-cache policy libopenfec
libopenfec:
  Installed: 1.4.2.4-5~ubuntu20.04
  Candidate: 1.4.2.4-5~ubuntu20.04
  Version table:
 *** 1.4.2.4-5~ubuntu20.04 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.4.2.4-4~ubuntu22.04 500
        500 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream/ubuntu jammy/main
```

```
david@david-pc:~$ apt-cache policy libroc
libroc:
  Installed: 0.1.5.r41.gc896873-11~ubuntu20.04
  Candidate: 0.1.5.r41.gc896873-11~ubuntu20.04
  Version table:
 *** 0.1.5.r41.gc896873-11~ubuntu20.04 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.1.5.r41.gc896873-10~ubuntu22.04 500
        500 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Does the 22.04 version of that ppa exist? If you added it, what would apt want to do?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thanks for the suggestion. That got most of it solved. There are a couple I can't seen to figure out though, namely libroc, libopenfec and libopenaptx0.

Comment: I'm glad that helped. If you post the apt-policy outputs for the remaining packages, that might give some useful info.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I've edited the post with the policy for those packages

Comment: Thanks! So they are "orphaned" - not from any PPA or repo that is currently attached to your apt system. If I were in your shoes, I'd try to use synaptic to downgrade those packages to the ones from the ppa. You may encounter dependency problems if the 3 packages are inter-related.

Comment: To do that in synaptic, you select the package, then in the Package menu select Force Version, then pick the ppa version from the dropdown box. Or use aptitude as explained here https://askubuntu.com/a/900538/243321